# Error message requesting for download link for Autodesk Forge, Reality Capture API

Tags: curl, autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I have just completed processing a photoscene, but when I try to retrieve the OBJ file from the downlink, I find it is an error file instead. I don't understand what it means about an anonymous GET requests.

Can someone help me out?

```sh
curl -s $FORGE_URL/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/5Hq3Z7fTmzLuUbKD564PmirBmNjyhMTAGzyvcl3kBCg?format=obj " . "-H 'Content-Type: application/json' " . "-H 'Authorization: Bearer $access_token' "
```

the resulting file  (result.obj.zip) is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
    <Message>Request specific response headers cannot be used for anonymous GET requests.</Message>
    <RequestId>E7127B72F224C27A</RequestId>
    <HostId>djRejqsBaI0eQ/M+kLuftyfaHw2gVOOoUGkoPXgVgP9nNhmATe9QS4AlhnZTtNYh49zU4Avd1PU=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again and remove the `Content-Type` from the header.

Per [RFC 7231 section 3.1.5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) `Content-Type` should be set only for PUT and POST requests. `GET` requests should have no body payload and hence be without `Content-Type` specified.